# Can you pass an array as input to a geometry shader?

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader

Can you pass an array of vec2's to a geometry shader as input? If so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays of arrays in GLSL are read left to right. `vec2[3][6]` is read as "an array of 3 elements, where each element is an array of 6 elements, where each element is a `vec2`."

GS inputs are arrayed; each element represents a single output from the preceding shader stage. The fact that the "single output" may actually be an array type is irrelevant.

So if you're using input/output variables that are not in interface blocks, this would look like this:

```
//Vertex Shader
out vec2[6] someVariable;

//Geometry Shader
in vec2[][6] someVariable;
```

The first index is the vertex index.

Note that this may require GLSL 4.30 or the ARB_arrays_of_arrays.

If you use [interface blocks](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Input_and_output) to pass data, then the array goes on the instance name of the interface block itself:

```
//Vertex Shader
out SomeName
{
  vec2[6] someVariable;
};

//Geometry Shader
in SomeName
{
  vec2[6] someVariable;
} instanceName[];
```

Since the block has an instance name, you would refer to it in GLSL as `instanceName[index].someVariable`.

This can be done in OpenGL 3.2.